# $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\ln n}$: If ln 1 doesn't exist, it doesn't impact convergence right?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

There's an obvious singularity at n=1, however the series still passes the Alternating Series Test.

The question asks to find out if there is "absolute" convergence. I should do the ratio test right?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Absolute convergence asks if the sum of the absolute value of the terms converges.  I would suggest trying to find a lower bound for the the absolute series and show that the lower bound also diverges.

Comment: Also closely related to the anti-derivative of the dirichlet eta function at $1$.

Comment: There is no convergence because the first term of the series isn't even defined. Typically when you have a logarithm in the denominator the summation index starts at 2, so this is either a typo or a trick question.